# Is it possible to use a single Yammer API Key across multiple Networks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, oauth, yammer

I have generated an Yammer API key within a network and the API key is working for read/write data across this network. But when I try to use the same API key to access data from a different network it shows an error.

```
unexpected token at 'Your network is not allowed to request an OAuth token for this Application'
```

Is the API key restricted to using on that particular network only ? Is it possible to use a single API key more generally to retrieve data from another networks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*By default it is tied to your organisation. You need to publish the app to the app directory for it to be available for everyone. Are there only particular networks where you want it to work? This requires additional configuration on the Yammer side. A clunky workaround is to create app IDs in the other networks where you need to run your app and allow the user to select the appropriate one. It depends on what you are trying to do.*

Note : Verbatim copy from the Yammer Developer Network, as answered to my question here, https://www.yammer.com/yammerdevelopersnetwork/#/Threads/show?threadId=292877375